# Javaによる､日付のローカライズ｡

Tags: android, java, localization

Javaで`ISO 8601`による日付を言語毎に日本語なら`yyyy年MM月dd日`､英語なら`Feb(MM) dd,yyyy`のように表示したいのですが､なにか良いライブラリはありますか｡

対応したい言語は日本語､英語､中国語､フランス語､インドネシア語です｡

**追記:**
アプリの種類はAndroidです｡

Comment: 質問にアプリの種類(スタンドアロン/Web/Android)や今使用しているフレームワーク等を記載すると、よりよい回答が得られるかもしれません

Comment: アドバイス有難うございます｡  
アプリの種類はAndroidです｡  質問に追記しておきました｡

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) / [joda-time-android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) ([ISODateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html))

---

*PrintI18NTimes.java*:

```java
import java.util.*;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class PrintI18NTimes {
    public static void main( String[] args) {
        // Input:
        final String iso_date_str = "2015-02-14T01:02+01:00";
        final DateTimeFormatter parser = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser();
        final DateTime dateTime = parser.parseDateTime( iso_date_str);

        // Output:
        final DateTimeFormatter ft_full = DateTimeFormat.fullDate();
        final DateTimeFormatter ft_mediam = DateTimeFormat.mediumDate();
        final DateTimeFormatter ft_short = DateTimeFormat.shortDate();
        final List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        for ( DateTimeFormatter formatter : new DateTimeFormatter[] {ft_full, ft_mediam, ft_short}) {
            lines.add( "Japanese  : " + formatter.withLocale( Locale.JAPANESE).print( dateTime));
            lines.add( "English   : " + formatter.withLocale( Locale.ENGLISH).print( dateTime));
            lines.add( "Chinese   : " + formatter.withLocale( Locale.CHINESE).print( dateTime));
            lines.add( "French    : " + formatter.withLocale( Locale.FRENCH).print( dateTime));
            lines.add( "Indonesian: " + formatter.withLocale( new Locale("id", "ID")).print( dateTime));
            lines.add( "");
        }
        System.out.println( "When is the Valentine day ?\n(Hint: " + iso_date_str + ")\n=====\n");
        for ( String line : lines)  System.out.println( line);
    }
}
```

*Output*:

```
When is the Valentine day ?
(Hint: 2015-02-14T01:02+01:00)
=====

Japanese  : 2015年2月14日
English   : Saturday, February 14, 2015
Chinese   : 2015年2月14日 星期六
French    : samedi 14 février 2015
Indonesian: Sabtu 14 Februari 2015

Japanese  : 2015/02/14
English   : Feb 14, 2015
Chinese   : 2015-2-14
French    : 14 févr. 2015
Indonesian: 14 Feb 15

Japanese  : 15/02/14
English   : 2/14/15
Chinese   : 15-2-14
French    : 14/02/15
Indonesian: 14/02/15
```

Comment: 丁寧な回答をありがとう御座います｡
`mediumDate`を使って実装できそうです｡
\Happy Valentine!/